# Get object path in Gnome Shell / GJS

Tags: javascript, gnome, clutter, gnome-shell

I'm writing a GNOME Shell extension and I need to save some information that will help me retrieve arbitrary (user selected) objects in the Gnome Shell interface across sessions, or at least statically generated actors/objects.

Given an existing Clutter actor alien to my code, yet sent to one of my signal handlers, how can I figure out its place in the overall widget hierarchy of Gnome Shell?